# Why is the last element of vector words not analyzed & how does it go outside the range?

Tags: c++, vector, range

I successfully print the # of sixes, threes, and twos, but not the one, and the program errors out for going outside the range of *words* after I return 0;

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    words.push_back("Six");
    words.push_back("Six");
    words.push_back("Six");
    words.push_back("Six");
    words.push_back("Six");
    words.push_back("Six");
    words.push_back("Three");
    words.push_back("Three");
    words.push_back("Three");
    words.push_back("Two"); 
    words.push_back("Two");
    words.push_back("One");

    vector<int> values; // vector to tracks the # of times a string
                        //appears in the vecotor words

    //create elements in values equal to number of 
    //elements in words
    //note: this creates too many elements
    //I am aware but am a begginner and don't know how
    //to solve this issue
    for (int i = 0; i <= words.size() - 1; i++) 
    {
        values.push_back(0);
    }

    int invariant = 0; // tracks number of times loops
    string current; // used make sure duplicate strings aren't recounted

    while (invariant <= words.size() - 1) 
    {
        //compare each element of words to each other element 
        //one at a time and increment the appropriate
        //element of values if they match
        for (int i = 0; i <= words.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            if (words[invariant] == words[i])
            {
                values[invariant] = values[invariant] + 1;
            }
        }
        //used to check for duplicate strings
        current.clear();
        current = words[invariant];

        if (invariant + 1 > words.size()) //avoids going outside range of words
        {
            return 0; //Errors outside range after this return
        }
        else{
            if (words[invariant+1] == current) // if the next word is the same
            {
                ++invariant;
            }
            else //if the next word is different output the number of times the current word appears
            {
                cout << current << " appears " << values[invariant] << " times.\n";
                ++invariant;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have been working on this code for a couple hours now and finally got to this point. I have been teaching myself c++ for a week. How can I check if the current word equals the next word without going outside the range at the end.

Note: I usually use invariant <= value for loops but without invariant == value - 1 the program would error out for being outside range of words.

The objective of the program is to output how many times each string in *words* occurs in *words*.

Comment: Why `<= words.size() - 1` instead of `< words.size()`? The latter form is the standard way to write loops and the former is wrong if the size happens to be `0` because the type of `words.size()`, and then also generally of `words.size() - 1`, is unsigned. You should have been taught the latter form in whatever material you are learning from.

Comment: learn about `std::map`. Then use `map<string,int>` for the counting - this way the task becomes trivial.

Comment: In a vector with `N` elements, valid subscripts range (inclusively) between `0` and `N-1`. That is why you got an out-of-range error. Loops generally are written using `<` rather than `<=`. For example, `for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) { ... }`.

Comment: @Eugene is right. Will your instructor allow you to use `std::map`? If so, you should try it.

Comment: Are all the duplicates of a given word stored next to each other? Or can they be in any order? For example, is `one, two, one, two, two` a valid sequence? Or do all the `ones` have to be next to each other? Like this: `one, one, two, two, two`.

Comment: I should have added this but I am self-taught. I am learning from a book I bought several years ago.

I think when I tried a loop using < words.size() I still got the range error. I can use std::map. I am learning from a book and the task was to "Write a program to count how many times a distinct word appears in it's input."

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, you should do:

`vector<int> values(words.size());`

at initialization.

This code:

`if (invariant + 1 > words.size())`

lets invariant go past the vector's bounds.

You should do:

`if(invariant == words.size())`

Comment: I figured that might be an issue but I had tried so many different changes and solutions by this point my brain hurt lol

Answer (score 1):

A lot of (online) C++ material is pretty out of date and still shows things like raw loops (where they are not needed). Currently C++ has much better abstractions you can use to write readable code. Like range-based for loops.

As Eugene mentions your problem can easily be solved using a std::map>
And your code would look something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words{"one","two","three", "four", "one", "three", "one", "four"};
    std::map<std::string,int> word_counts;

    // range based for loop, cannot go out of range
    // const means the loop is not allowed to modifiy words (only read them)
    // auto means the compiler should lookup the type for word (which will be std::string)
    // the & is a reference and will prevent words from being copied (copy constructor not called)
    for(const auto& word : words)
    {
        // if no entry at [word] a new entry will be made and initialized to zero
        // then count is incremented
        word_counts[word]++; 
    }

    // use structured binding to enumerate all
    // key value pairs in map and give them readable names (word and count)
    for(const auto& [word,count] : word_counts)
    {
        std::cout << "Word : `" << word << "` has count : " << count << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I up-voted this because it is so elegant. @MetalGooseSolid, take note. This may not be something you can turn in to your teacher, but it is the way a professional would do this.

Comment: Well OP could ofcourse still show this to his teacher ;)

Comment: Visual Studio was using c++ 14 by default so it failed to compile, but I figured out how to change it to c++ 20. So thanks I learned something extra! Just to clarify, are maps the industry standard?

Comment: Maps are part of the standard library so always available. There are more datastructures like that available, have a look here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container. So yes they are definitely part of the standard. And should IMO be taught right from the start.

Comment: The code I wrote is probably C++17 compatible, but yes C++20 will do fine. You might also want to have a look at this : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Answer (score 1):

As was noted in the comments, a map is the easiest way to solve this. Because you did not mention maps in your question, and also because this appears to be a homework assignment of some sort, I will assume that you have not yet studied maps. The algorithm below does not use maps. It uses vectors.

I coded a solution to this based upon the assumption that duplicates of a given word are stored next to each other in the vector. If that is not true, then I would call `std::sort` to sort the vector, before doing anything else.

To tabulate the results, I declared two "parallel" arrays:

```cpp
    std::vector<std::string> unique_words;
    std::vector<int> counts;
```

I would have preferred to declare a `struct` that holds a word and its count, but did not, because I figured that an "array of structs" is something you have not yet studied.

So, parallel vectors. Every time I encounter a new word, I push it onto the back of vector `uniuqe_words`, and, at the same time, I push the value `1` onto the back of vector `counts`. To get things started, I pushed the first element from vector `words` onto my vector of `unique_words`:

```cpp
        unique_words.push_back(words[0]);
        counts.push_back(1);
```

Next, I ran a loop to check all the other `words`, beginning with `words[1]`. Inside the loop, I used an if-statement to check whether the new element from vector `words` was already on the back of the vector `unique_words`. If so, I incremented the count on the back of vector `counts`; otherwise, I pushed the word onto the back of vector `unique_words`, and gave it a count of 1.

```cpp
            if (words[i] == unique_words.back())
                ++counts.back();
            else
            {
                unique_words.push_back(words[i]);
                counts.push_back(1);
            }
```

And that is the heart of the algorithm.

I don't want to say anything more, because I think this is a homework assignment. My goal is to provide legitimate help to a student, not to code his program for him. I hope you're cool with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it's important to learn both the efficient way of doing things (maps) , but also to learn how to solve the problem the way I thought it up. 

if you push.back() an integer into an element already containing a value does it automatically add them together or is that one of the things intentionally missing ;-)

Comment: `++counts.back();` does the adding. It increments the count that was initialized to `1` by the statement `counts.push_back(1);`. Function `push_back` does not modify an existing element. It adds a new element at the end of the vector. `unique_words` and `counts` start out as empty vectors, so `push_back` is called on them whenever a new word is found.

Comment: I missed the ++ >_<